# Does mother feed information?

Tags: brain, children, information

Does the mother feed information to the child in the fetus? If so, How is that done? IF not, How can the just born baby breath involuntarily if brain doesn't know it should generate impulses to contract and expand Diaphragm ? If information is given, What type of Information it is, And Would it be possible to feed the information of mother's choice?

Comment: You might want to look at this question https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/31459/how-is-instinct-carried-from-one-generation-to-another

Comment: It's not like anyone can not breath for long without other access to oxygen. Pain is pretty good informant.

Answer (score -1):

Why was this downvoted? It's a decent question even if somewhat dumb.

Humans don't breathe in the womb. Instead, blood with oxygen and other essentials goes in through the umbilical cord and back out through the same cord after its resources have been partially used.

"Feeding information" would require a neural connection which there isn't any evidence of. Experiments where scientists "link human brains together" generally use an electricity-based computer-mediated connection (for a good example: 
https://www.cnet.com/news/scientists-connected-3-actual-human-brains-then-made-them-play-tetris/ )